# Using attributes in Model.calculate method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

OK So I've got my models like so:

```
Team
  has_many :users, :through => memberships

User
  has_one :user_status
```

Now in my Team model I want to be able to find the maximum `'updated_at'` value of my `'user_status'` models.

I tried doing something like:

```
Team
  has_many :users, :through => :memberships
  has_many :user_statuses, :through => :users

  def max_last_updated_status
    user_statuses.maximum(:updated_at)
  end
```

but that gave me:

```
Invalid source reflection macro :has_one for has_many :user_statuses, :through => :users.  Use :source to specify...
```

So I was wondering if there's a better way of doing this, can I just create a property of the User model like:

```
def status_updated_at
  user_status.updated_at
end
```

and then change my Team class to have:

```
  def max_last_updated_status
    user.maximum(:status_updated_at)
  end
```

? I'm assuming not as `'status_updated_at'` is not really a column and so the sql generation would fail...

Another perspective on this problem would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your original approach, have you tried this:

```
team.users.maximum "user_statuses.updated_at", :include => :user_status
# OR
team.users.maximum "`user_statuses`.updated_at", :include => :user_status
```

I tried with following classes and it works just fine:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user_status
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :teams, :through => :memberships
end


class UserStatus < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end


class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, :through => :memberships
  has_many :memberships
end


class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment: Oh I didn't realise you could do that, but of course it makes sense when you add the include, I can see how the SQL gets generated. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

I would do it this way:

Team

```
has_many :users, :through => memberships

def max_last_updated_status
  users.map{|user| user.user_status.updated_at}.max
end
```

User

```
has_one :user_status
```

The method max_last_updated_status should return the max updated_at of the users in the team.

Comment: I like this answer, it's just the change in perspective I needed. Moving away from thinking SQL and start thinking Ruby. I've implemented it like this. Thanks a lot.